# Constraint optimization in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, constraints

Let's consider following pair of constraints:

$$x-M*b\le0$$
$$x-a*b\ge0$$

Where $M$ is a huge number and $a$ is a usually quite small one ($a<M$), both are real numbers. $b$ is a binary variable $\{0,1\}$.

This pair of constraints represent a logical $XOR$ hence, the quantity of $x$ is eighter $0$ or $\ge a$. 
Especially the second one causes some trouble while solving the whole model. The performance of the solving process depends heavily on the value of $a$. In some cases, the model becomes even infeasible.

Does someone has an idea on how to efficiently relax the constraint or a way to determine a proper value of $a$ beforehand? I've tried lagrange relaxation so far but I wasn't impressed by the results.

Comment: what does the first constraint have to do with the question you asked?

Comment: Nothing. The first one just ensures that the binary variable is turned to 1 in case that x is greater than 0.